# Is it possible to overlay a scatterplot on map using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to draw a map of French departements (ie districts in France) and plot points on the map. I use ggplot2 to draw the map but when I want to add points on the map, R returns an error which says that it cannot find 'group'.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggmap")

# load the contour of French departements
wg  <- read.csv("data/departements.csv")

metropoles  <- c("Paris", "Rennes", "Rouen", "Lille", "Marseille")
geo  <- geocode(metropoles)
met  <- data.frame(ville = metropoles, geo)

map  <- ggplot(data = wg, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
geom_polygon() + 
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-7,10)) + 
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(40,53)) + 
coord_map() + 
theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank()) 

map + geom_point(data = met, aes(x = lon, y = lat))
```

For replication, you can find the raw data [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/blaquans/bd4354916033fa1c496d/raw/departements.csv) and the R program [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pachevalier/bd4354916033fa1c496d/raw/map.R)

Comment: `map + geom_point(data = met, aes(x = lon, y = lat, group=NULL))`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why we have to add this option ?

Comment: You defined it in the "global" `aes`, but there is no `group` column in `met`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Roland had the good answer. The problem is that I had defined group as a general argument.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = wg, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-7,10)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(40,53)) + 
  coord_map() + 
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank()) 
  geom_point(data = met, aes(x = lon, y = lat))
```